# Spring boot consumer without using @Kafkalistener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to write kafka consumer without using @Kafkalistener  and below are the lines of code that I am using for configuring listener:

```
@Configuration
    @EnableKafka
    public class KafkaConfig {

      @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
      private String bootstrapServers;

      @Bean
      public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        // list of host:port pairs used for establishing the initial connections to the Kafka cluster
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class);
        // allows a pool of processes to divide the work of consuming and processing records
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "org");
        // automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        return props;
      }

      @Bean
      public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
      }

      @Bean
      public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
          ContainerProperties containerProperties=new ContainerProperties("in.t");
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
      }

      @Bean
      public Consumer receiver() {
        return new Consumer();
      }
    }
```

Here how can I configure the topic and listener method and my consumer class can have multiple methods .

Also, wanted to know if there are any potential issues faced while using @kafkalistener with kafka streams.

PS: I don't want to use @KafkaListener.

Comment: why you don't to use kafka listener? @user

Comment: beacuse it doesnt work with streams

Answer (score 2):

1. The `@kafkalistener` doesn't work with Kafka Streams. It is for plain `Consumer`. The Kafka Stream can be managed via `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` and particular `@Bean` for the `KStream`.
2. If you don't want to use a `@kafkalistener`, then you need to go a direction with the manual `KafkaListenerContainer` creation. The `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` can be used for that purpose, but only since Spring Kafka `2.2` and definitely not wit the Spring Boot.

So, you don't have choice unless to create a `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` instead manually. And already here via `ContainerProperties` you can inject a target `messageListener`. For you custom `Consumer` POJO you need to consider wrap it into the `RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter`. And only the last one has to be injected into the  `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`.

That's how things work underneath with the `@KafkaListener`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just manually create `KafkaConsumer`, subscribe it to needed topics and poll records starting from earliest/latest offset:

```
Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
config.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
config.put(CommonClientConfigs.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "id");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST.name().toLowerCase());
config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer");
....
config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaProtobufDeserializer.class);
config.put(KafkaProtobufDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_PROTOBUF_KEY_TYPE, String.class.getName());
config.put(KafkaProtobufDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_PROTOBUF_VALUE_TYPE, YourProtobufEvent.class.getName());

try(var consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, YourProtobufEvent>(config)) {
  consumer.subscribe(singleton("your-topic"));
  YourProtobufEvent record = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).iterator().next().value();
  assertThat(record.getId()).isEqualTo("1");
}
```

Depending on the need, you can fetch specific partition/offset, use `while (true)` to constantly listen for records or have separate `Thread`s with multiple consumers

Comment: This is the proper answer

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot and Spring Kafka it's possible to create consumers without @KafkaListener and creation additional explicit kafka's beans (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer, etc ...):

1. application.yml - create connection configs. They will be injected into KafkaProperties

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    producer:
      key-serializer: "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
      value-serializer: "org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer"
    listener:
      type: BATCH
    consumer:
      clientId: "applicationClientId"
      groupId: "applicationGroup"
      keyDeserializer: "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
      valueDeserializer: "org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer"
      maxPollRecords: 50
      fetchMinSize: 50
      autoOffsetReset: earliest
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: "*"
```

2. Based on KafkaProperties, spring-boot will create necessary beans. So, it's required to create only useful topic endpoints for data processing.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
@RequiredArgsConstructor //Lombok annotation
public class KafkaConsumerConfig implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {

    private final BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private final SomethingApplicationService somethingApplicationService

    @SneakyThrows //Lombok annotation
    @Override
    public void configureKafkaListeners(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        // The following may be in a loop with different services and topics
        val endpoint = new MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, KafkaReceiptRequest>();

        endpoint.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        endpoint.setBean(somethingApplicationService);
        endpoint.setMethod(somethingApplicationService.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("processList", List.class));
        endpoint.setId("Unique id for this endpoint");
        endpoint.setTopics("topic1", ...);
        endpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());

        registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
        return new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    }

}
```

3. Target service and data object

```
@Service
public class SomethingApplicationService {

    public void processList(List<Data> list) {
        //processing logic
    }

}

@Data //Lombok annotation
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```